# Which jar file does contain jersey LoggingFeature class?

Tags: java, logging, jersey

I am trying to find the `org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature` class to add to my project.  Javadoc about this class found here:  https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html
It is not in the jersey-common.jar. Which jar file does contain it?

Answer (score 4):

You can find this class in the jar Jersey Commmons.

Maven repository:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.23.2

Comment: Thank you. It turned out I had jersey-common.jar ver. 2.22.2, which did not have it.

Comment: I am having the same problem finding it, but I cannot use version 2.23 or 2.25 which have it. I have Jersey 2.7 in my project and it is more or less incompatible with any version except 2.7. Do you know where it moved to in 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Try this seach: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature%22

I found this class in both these dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
</dependency>
```

In fact, `jaxrs-ri` depends on `jersey-common`.

What `jersey-common` version are you using?

Comment: It turned out I had jersey-common.jar ver. 2.22.2, which did not have it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use grepcode.com when I need to find jars that contain specific classes.

http://grepcode.com/search/?query=org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature